# Question layout all messed up

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, information-display

Maybe I'm just going mad, but with a bounty in place, the recent-elongated "action list" on a question seems to be [screwing up the layout of SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180909/stdstring-npos-validity).

I've not seen this before.

Firefox 4.0.1 here.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the [SE Modifications](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an) userscript installed? I think that without the timeline and history links, it (barely) fits in this case. It'd be better if that list of links just wrapped to two lines, though. I also think this has been brought up before, but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: @TimStone: Ah, yes, I do! Disabling it fixes the layout. I hadn't realised that the addition of those links was related to my installation of the plugin. I'd still suggest that this implies a non-robust layout, but I guess one could now _only just_ think about calling it a bug. It's also notable that I do not see this at all usually; I'm not sure what that indicates. I believe it's only on bounty questions, but given this new information I'd want to re-verify that before swearing by it.

Comment: I think it'll only occur on questions that belong to you and have been edited, since you have extra links in that situation. Then if you're a 10K/mod/dev user, there are even more options to contend with. In any case, I definitely agree about the layout. I'm going to mess around with it a bit to see if I can suggest a better approach for them to take, and I'll modify the userscript to handle this situation better in the meantime.

Comment: FWIW, I moved "timeline" to seperate line in my [script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-hidden-links) @Tim.

Comment: @TimStone: That'll be it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/809/the-user-signature-box-drifting-into-the-tag-info-box

Comment: why doesn't that box wrap again?

Comment: Somehow this got pushed out longer than it should have, but I've updated the userscript now to force a break in the links in this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing this, as it is not a site issue, but a custom user script causing it.  You're welcome to use scripts, of course....but if it breaks, it breaks - not a bug in the site itself.

Comment: A custom user script is not causing the bug (which is that the layout expands, rather than that the links fall down onto separate lines). The user script merely makes the bug visible to the user.

Comment: @Tomalak - I totally disagree, it *is* causing the issue.  *If* we added that many links (and we wouldn't) we'd make them fall down, but the interface and layout isn't designed for that many links - it's designed for a fixed width.  The script, *not* the site, is cramming more than is designed to fit in that space.  If your hard drive is out of space because you downloaded something 400GB too large, would you blame the total space on the drive, or your download as the cause for you being out of space?

Comment: Bah.. :P