# Please make entries in "responses" link to the respones directly

Tags: feature-request, responses

When following a link in the "activity" page, you are directed to the entry directly. That is, if the activity was a comment, you directly jump to the comment.

But in the "responses" page, if you follow an entry and the entry relates to a *question*, you merely jump to that question and not to the response itself. (If the entry relates to an answer, then you jump to the comment itself, as expected.)

I find that behavior annoying, as it makes it difficult to directly link to a response, in particular if that response was a comment. I need to inspect the page source to find the comment-id to link to.

Comment: Seems to work for me. For a comment listed on the "responses" page, when I click on the relevant question title I'm directed straight to the comment in question. The link is like `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96097/question-layout-all-messed-up/96100#comment-241627`

Comment: @Tomalak weird. it doesn't do that for me.

Comment: It works for me too: a link to a comment in the "responses" tab takes me to the comment, and a link to an answer takes me to that answer.

Comment: @Kiam if you go to "http://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb?tab=responses" and click on the comment "@Johannes: The idea of having references seems very dangerous to me, because the references will ..." or to "@Johannes: I suppose if the end iterator points to a sentinel value within the container, then the" does it take you to the comment?

Comment: @Tomalak ^^^^^^

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb I cannot access your "responses" tab. If I look at your account page, I see just three tabs: "stats," "bounties," and "accounts." I can only try on my account, and I cannot reproduce what you are reporting.

Comment: Actually I'm seeing the same thing @Tomalak and @kiamlaluno are seeing, the links do indeed include the `#comment-xxxx` pieces which link to the comment directly, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Daniel it appears that links to comments to questions do not include the "comment-xxxx" pieces. But only links to comments to answers do.

Comment: Related: [Comment links on Responses tab do not work correctly when the comment is hidden](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94486)

Comment: @Tomalak ^^^^^^^

Comment: @kiam ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @Johannes: Ah, yes. For comments on answers the functionality is present; for comments on questions, not. Whether the bug is that the comment anchor is missing for entries relating to questions, or that the comment rather than _answer_ anchor is used for entries relating to answers, there is a bug here.

Comment: Hence the real complaint is about not wanting to fix it, and not wanting to handle the collapsed comments.... not really about whether the link is useful or not. If the link weren't useful, I have no real reason why it still works in some cases at all.

Comment: @Tomalak and Johannes: The comment anchor is present. I [just requested that it should be used for questions, too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107596/comment-links-in-activity-and-responses-should-always-take-me-directly-to-the), and found this very question only now.