# Comment links in "activity" and "responses" should always take me directly to the comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, recent-activity, responses

The comment links in the "activity" and "responses" tabs of the user profile [now work correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94486/comment-links-on-responses-tab-do-not-work-correctly-when-the-comment-is-hidden/107511#107511) when the comment would be hidden behind "add / show *n* more comments". This is great! However, it appears that we have comment links **only for comments to *answers***, not to questions.

For example, [on my "activity" tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155585/hendrik-vogt?tab=activity#page_2-filter_comments) I see the link
[Comments that fail to post start the “You can only comment every 5 seconds” timer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer) to a comment @Matthew (timestamp  2011-09-26 14:23:23), and it takes me to the *question*. I'd expect a link that takes me directly to the comment, [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer#comment-276388).

<sup>(It actually took me some time to figure out what's happening; apparently [I'm not the only one confused by this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96148/please-make-entries-in-responses-link-to-the-respones-directly).)</sup>

Comment: Related: The [Direct link to a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5436/146495) question describes how this works, and Shog9 notes: *"However, this relies on specific aspects of the current implementation, and there's no guarantee they won't change at some point in the future. Don't count on these links being permanent!"*.

Comment: @Kevin: They even [bothered pre-expanding the "show more comments"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94486/comment-links-on-responses-tab-do-not-work-correctly-when-the-comment-is-hidden/107511#107511), which I highly appreciate, so I'm confident those links will also work in the future - _at least when I come from my "activity" or "responses" tab_.

Comment: I think that the code that generated the hash fragments for those questions was updated, and the fact that the question links never had them to begin with was just overlooked, so hopefully a quick-fix. The client-side code works equally fine with comments on questions, so no issue there.

Comment: It's great that this feature now works correctly for answers. Now to make it so for questions, too!